# How can I detect when a new InputDevice is connected to an android device?

Tags: android, device, hid

I need to detect when a new device is connected to my android devices.

Currently I keep periodically pooling `InputDevice.getDeviceIds()`, but this solution has its own drawbacks.

Comment: create a broad cast receiver for detecting input device's connection status..

Comment: @SinoRaj You mean using InputManager? This class was added at API level 16. I'm targeting older APIs. Is there a way to do what I need on level 8?